# How to get only the first value/property of each object

Tags: arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to get the first value, in other words each of the objects.name to be printed/logged.

In this example, I would like Tom, Tom, Fox

```
     var tom = {
      name: "Tom",
      age: 23,
      location: "London"
    };

    var tom2 = {
      name: "Tom",
      age: 21,
      location: "London"
    };
    var fox = {
      name: "Fox",
      age: 23,
      location: "London"
    };

    var arr = [tom, tom2, fox];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var objectArr = arr[i]
      for (var prop in objectArr) {
      var values = objectArr[prop];
        console.log(values)
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `forEach` built-in array function. [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
arr.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
    var x = arrayItem.name;
    console.log(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One short way would be:

```
var arr = [tom, tom2, fox];
console.log(arr.map(el => el.name));
```

Using the function [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on Array to get an array with only the object field you want and then the `console.log` function can take an array for argument and print it.